# Regular expression - value not equal to 0,00

Tags: javascript, regex, dojo

I have a regular expression to validate a input value.

At this point I have:

```
([0-9]{0,3}[.]?)*[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]*|[0-9]
```

Its working, but now I need to add a validation to see if the value is not 0,00

The input is an amount value.
Possible values:

```
12,31
1.234,56
1.234.567,89
```

Not possible values:

```
0,00
```

I need this to use in dijit.form.ValidationTextBox .
Something like:

```
dijit.byId(nameID).regExp = "([0-9]{0,3}[.]?)*[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]*|[0-9]";
```

Comment: How about `if (value != "0,00") { ... }`?

Comment: from what i know i need to use dijit.byId(nameID).regExp and it only accept regular expresions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to rethink your regurlar expression completely, because it testes true strings like "1.23.4,56" and "0,", but I don't think it's what you want.

Try something like this:

```
(?:(?:[1-9]\d{0,2})(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})|0,(?:[1-9]\d|0[1-9]))
```

Test your regular expression with [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), but keep in mind that Javascript doesn't support *all* the features of the most complete regex engines. In fact, it's quite poor.

Some more notes:

1. Don't use the token `[.]` to match a dot. It's slow. Just escape the dot: `\.`
2. You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` for short, and you can use it in square brackets too: `[a-f\d\-]` for all hexadecimal integer chars.

Comment: almost there, but its no valid to something like 11.111.111.111.111.110,00

Comment: Why, wasn't that number valid? Testing that number would yeld true.

Comment: Its not working with the dijit.byId(nameID).regExp for some reason. I will mark this as right answer because its working with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

Comment: Ah, yes, I get it now. That's because you have to escape those `\d`, because you're actually defining a *string* and not a regular expression. So you have to write `\\d` instead, and so `\\.`

Comment: Work like a charm. I just needed to escape the string like you said. Thanks

Comment: Just a question... why don't you simply use ranges with min ?